# Best Way To Create Dynamic Related DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-controls

So, I have three drop down lists that are related to each other:

- CountryDDL
- CityDDL
- ZipcodeDDL

Obviously the options in the CityDDL are created when the CountryDDL's OnSelectedIndexChanged event is fired, and ZipcodeDDL is created when the CityDDL OnSelectedIndexChanged event is fired.

That's all good....but what I'm wanting to do is dynamically insert multiple instances of these related controls.

I need to be able to click a button and add as many instances of these three related drop downs as a user needs.

Any ideas for best way to accomplish this preserving state and having all events work as they should??

I'm using .Net 4.0 and the current Telerik release.

Comment: Is the best way to do this via dynamically loaded Usercontrols??  How well does that scale?  Should I be doing this via JQuery instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your controls into a user control or custom web control and implement the logic for the simple control dependency. The hosting user or web control acts as naming container and all will work fine if you nest this control in an outer control like a repeater or grid.

Comment: It's actually not quite that easy.  The application is using mvp and the controls referenced above live in a dynamically loaded usercontrol already.  If I put the three dropdowns in a seperate usercontrol and load it during PageLoad everything looks good until I fire an event on one of the dropdowns....I'm not able to keep state.  Also, I cannot load multiple instances of the drop down usercontrol...it always reloads the first one.

Comment: Do you create your controls in PageInit of the user control? Otherwise your ViewState is broken!

Comment: Which controls are you referring to?  In the hosting page I've overridden the OnPreInit event and am trying to add the usercontrol there.  I've also tried OnInit as well.....either way I either ViewState is broken (I can insert the first control, but on post backs it disappears) or I get the following error:  The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.  Help!!!

Comment: I did end up using a usercontrol, thought it's not nested in a repeater.  Thanks for taking a look Dirk!